# Webpack convert less fiels to css

Tags: webpack

In my webpack application I need to convert my dark theme and light theme less files into css. I am not sure how to target them specifically. I have two files `light-theme.less` and `dark-theme.less`. I made a gulp task that does this but I dont know how to do it in webpack and store it in the public folder of my app. My first instinct was something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\-theme.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

;

I need to access my css files in my index.html file which means I need the converted less-to-css files in my public directory (localhost:8080/light-theme.css).

I have been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now any help is appreciated

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: Nothing, It doesnt generate a public folder with themes